# Cannot connect via Lighttable to clojure

Tags: clojure, leiningen, lighttable

Just started up with clojure and am a really beginner at clojure. I have downloaded leiningen and i am able to compile source code.

However, I am trying to follow a tutorial using lighttable and when i am trying to connect

(ns learningclojure)

followed by cmd-enter

I receive the following error message. Any clue what i shall do? I have tried to give sufficient permission but it still won't work

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied. Please check your access rights for /private/var/folders/6y/x_j__0l93gv9fgm612mqxh2c0000gn/T/AppTranslocation/2F779AE0-FA53-4B43-B38E-43852447A9AC/d/LightTable.app/Contents/Resources/app/plugins/Clojure/runner/resources/.nrepl-port
    at leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke(repl.clj:317)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke(RestFn.java:425)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$light.invoke(light_nrepl.clj:77)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl$_main.doInvoke(light_nrepl.clj:85)
    at clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo(RestFn.java:137)
    at leiningen.light_nrepl.main(Unknown Source)
```

Versions:

macOS Sierra (10.12.3)
Leiningen 2.7.1 on Java 1.8.0_121 Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
REPL-y 0.3.7, nREPL 0.2.12
Clojure 1.8.0

Comment: Looks like this is the problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528746/osx-leiningen-permissions-error

Answer (score 0):

It appears that LightTable requires your user to have modify rights to it's application folders - this is definitely the case on Windows installations, and I suspect it's the same for linux.

Have you tried it as super (sudo) , just as a test?

If that does not help, try these:

1. Check this previous similar question: [OSX Leiningen permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528746/osx-leiningen-permissions-error)
2. Try 'lein clean' and 'rm ~/.lein-repl-history' - many a problem can be fixed this way. :)

Good luck :)