# Mac OS X - Brew installed Leiningen permission error / wrong directory

Tags: macos, clojure, homebrew, leiningen

I've never had issue installing Leiningen on multiple machines. But on a new Mac (MacOS 14.3), I can't get `lein repl` to work:

```
java.io.IOException: Permission denied. Please check your access rights for /Users/hbergier/.lein/repl-port
 at leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:458)
    leiningen.repl$repl.doInvoke (repl.clj:370)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:425)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invokeStatic (repl.clj:435)
    leiningen.repl$repl.invoke (repl.clj:370)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$partial_task$fn__7430.doInvoke (main.clj:284)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.invoke (RestFn.java:410)
    clojure.lang.AFn.applyToHelper (AFn.java:154)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:132)
    clojure.lang.AFunction$1.doInvoke (AFunction.java:31)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:669)
    clojure.core$apply.invoke (core.clj:662)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invokeStatic (main.clj:334)
    leiningen.core.main$apply_task.invoke (main.clj:320)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invokeStatic (main.clj:343)
    leiningen.core.main$resolve_and_apply.invoke (main.clj:336)
    leiningen.core.main$_main$fn__7523.invoke (main.clj:469)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.invokeStatic (main.clj:454)
    leiningen.core.main$_main.doInvoke (main.clj:451)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.core$apply.invokeStatic (core.clj:667)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invokeStatic (main.clj:514)
    clojure.main$main_opt.invoke (main.clj:510)
    clojure.main$main.invokeStatic (main.clj:664)
    clojure.main$main.doInvoke (main.clj:616)
    clojure.lang.RestFn.applyTo (RestFn.java:137)
    clojure.lang.Var.applyTo (Var.java:705)
    clojure.main.main (main.java:40)
```

The permission is not the issue so this post doesn't help: [OSX Leiningen permissions error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528746/osx-leiningen-permissions-error)

The issue is that ~/.lein/repl-port doesn't exist at all -- Brew didn't create such directory but installed everything at: `/usr/local/Cellar/leiningen/2.11.2/`

I've been unable to find a similar issue anywhere. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by doing the following (not sure if each step is needed) in the terminal from the home directory:

`brew uninstall leiningen`

`mkdir .lein`

`sudo chown -R <username> ~/.lein`

`brew install leiningen`

After that the repl worked fine. It probably helped to create the /.lein folder with the right permissions.

Note: this exact error also happened to one of my students (also on Mac OS, also using Homebrew) and the fixed worked for him as well.

Comment: Did you maybe previously run leiningen under sudo? That would explain why these steps were needed. (`mkdir .lein` should leave the directory owned by your name, no `sudo chown` needed, unless something else created it under the wrong user previously).

Comment: Nope. Leiningen had never been ran on this machine before. Very first installation worked but impossible to start Repl. This error also happened to someone else on Mac OS.

Comment: If you _hadn't_ run these commands we could get some diagnostics -- `ls -ld ~/.lein` for example might be informative -- but right now the evidence needed to figure out what the problem was has been destroyed.

Comment: (to be clear, `brew` isn't _supposed_ to create that directory --  if everything is working as intended, `lein` itself does when you first run it).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy As I said above, there was no such directory, ever. So that test would have failed. The directory wasn't created by running 'lean repl'.

Comment: I don't believe it until I've seen it with my own eyes.

Comment: ...well, for some value of "believe". Reading https://codeberg.org/leiningen/leiningen/src/branch/main/bin/lein#L331-L340, I could conceive of having some code using the newer `$XDG_CACHE_HOME/leiningen` directory and other code trying to use the old `~/.lein` combining to solve this problem (in which case `mkdir ~/.lein` would have been the _only_ step you needed to follow to solve the problem)... but again, the evidence has been destroyed so it's now impossible to determine what your original problem was.